# Iterate pandas row by row and modify specific "cells" in a python way

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm new to python and I have a pandas dataframe that I want to iterate row by row (like for example a 2d array in other languages).
The goal is something like this as a logic: (if df was a like 2d array)

```
for row in df:
    if df[row,2] == '' AND df[row,1] !='':
       df[row-1,1] = df[row,1]
       df[row,1] = ''
```

The point is: I want to move the contents of the the current row to the previous one in the column 1, if the current row,column 2 is empty and the current row,column 1 is not.

How would I do that in a python way? (without for example iterating with for loops). I saw something about vectorization but I don't really get how it works.

Or is it easier to convert the df into a list of lists, or an array? The files are big so I would like to use a fast way and I read from excel file, so I just used the read_excel of pandas to import it into a df.

Comment: Look at the [shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) method in Pandas. 1) Use shift to get the lagged version of your column 1 (lagged_col_1). 2) overwrite column 1 with lagged_col_1 if your logical test is true (col 2 is empty and col 1 is not). 3) Delete lagged_col_1.

Comment: What would you do when you encounter three consecutive rows that 1) all have a value in col1 and  2) col2 is empty in all three rows? Your current code will only replace the first row with the second, and leave the third row alone. Is that what you want?

Comment: @RichieV no it is really really specific for these files so i do not need anything else. They sometimes have this problem because of an error in the program that exports them (which is used by public hospitals so it's not easy to change anything in the export procedure), so I just needed a fast way to fix it because the files are big and loops seemed slow. As i said in a comment in anakhand's answer, it's around 70 times faster this way... I am reading on Pandas a lot these days and it seems amazing for these kinds of things!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (assuming by column 1 you meant the column at index 0, and by column 2, the one at index 1):

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

col1, col2 = df.columns[0], df.columns[1]
mask = (df.loc[:, col1] != '') & (df.loc[:, col2] == '')
mask.iloc[0] = False  # don't wrap around first row (even if the condition applies)
df.loc[mask.shift(-1, fill_value=False), col1] = df.loc[mask, col1].values
```

The key point here is using [`Series.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html#pandas-series-shift) to shift the boolean mask backwards by one. This only uses pandas/numpy vectorized functions, so it will be much better than iterating with a plain Python `for` loop.

### Step-by-step

0. [Get the labels of your columns: `col1, col2 = df.columns[0], df.columns[1]`]
1. Create a boolean mask which is `True` for the rows which satisfy your condition, i.e. nonempty first column *and* empty second column:

   ```py
   mask = (df.loc[:, col1] != '') & (df.loc[:, col2] == '')
   mask.iloc[0] = False
   ```

   Here we manually set the first element of the mask to `False`, since even if the first row satisfies the condition, we can't do anything with it (there is no previous row to copy the value of the first column to). (This isn't a problem for `Series.shift`, which doesn't wrap around, but it is when we're using this mask, in step 3, to select the values that we're going to assign, with `df.loc[mask, col1].values`: if `mask.iloc[0]` were `True`, we would have one more value than targets.)
2. Shift the mask backwards by one to obtain a mask of the rows to be modified (i.e. the rows that come immediately before a row that satisfies the condition):

   ```py
   mask.shift(-1, fill_value=False)
   ```

   Since we're shifting the mask backwards by one, the last element won't be defined, so we set it to `False` by using `fill_value=False`—we don't want to modify the last row.
3. Within column 1, assign the values of the rows satisfying the condition to their respective previous rows, using the two masks that we computed:

   ```py
   df.loc[mask.shift(-1, fill_value=False), col1] = df.loc[mask, col1].values
   ```

   Here we must use `.values` on the right-hand-side to get the raw numpy array of values, since if we leave it as a `Series`, pandas will try to align the indices of the lhs and rhs (and since we shifted the rows by one, the indices won't match, so the end result will contain `NaN`s); instead, we simply want to assign the first element of the rhs to the first slot of the lhs, the second element to the second slot, etc.

This is more or less the same approach as the one outlined by Chaos in the comments.

### Example

```py
>>> sample = pd.DataFrame([("spam", ""), ("foo", "bar"), ("baz", ""), ("", "eggs")])
>>> df = sample.copy()
>>> df
      0     1
0  spam
1   foo   bar
2   baz
3        eggs

>>> col1, col2 = df.columns[0], df.columns[1]
>>> mask = (df.loc[:, col1] != '') & (df.loc[:, col2] == '')
>>> mask.iloc[0] = False
>>> df.loc[mask.shift(-1, fill_value=False), col1] = df.loc[mask, col1].values
>>> df
      0     1
0  spam
1   baz   bar
2   baz
3        eggs
```

---

### Addendum

If you actually *do* want to make the value of the first row wrap around to the last row (if the condition applies to the first row)—i.e. you want to move the values around circularly—, you can use [`np.roll`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html) instead of `Series.shift`:

```py
mask = (df.loc[:, col1] != '') & (df.loc[:, col2] == '')
df.loc[np.roll(mask, -1), col1] = np.roll(df.loc[mask, col1].values, -1)
```

Then, continuing the previous example:

```py
>>> df = sample.copy()
>>> mask = (df.loc[:, col1] != '') & (df.loc[:, col2] == '')
>>> df.loc[np.roll(mask, -1), col1] = np.roll(df.loc[mask, col1].values, -1)
>>> df
      0     1
0  spam
1   baz   bar
2   baz
3  spam  eggs
```

Comment: wow very detailed answer! thanks a lot I will test on the files, and get back with marking it as the answer if everything works!!

Comment: It's really intuitive once you get used to it actually! And I calculated the time difference between this and a crude for loop (like the answer of archer for example) and it's about 70 times faster, for my files at least. I cannot stress how comprehensible your answer was!

Answer (score 1):

In case you will not find a more pythonic way, here is the correct code to do the work:

```
for i in range(1, len(df)):
    if df.iloc[i, 2]='' and df.iloc[i, 1]!='':
        df.iloc[i-1, 1]=df.iloc[i,1]
        df.iloc[i, 1]=''
```